# Is it possible to get upcoming event / show information from a Myspace page without scraping?

Tags: api, screen-scraping, myspace

I want to get show information from myspace artists.  One way I could do this is ask an artist to input their myspace URL and I could try to scrape the page.

What I would really like to do is ask the artist for their myspace credentials and use the myspace api to get their show data.  I cannot find how to do this on the myspace developers site.  Does anyone know?

And as a side question, if I decide to go the page scraping route, is that legal?  I feel like a lot of people do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out http://livekick.com . It includes all music concerts posted on myspace.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this great article](http://www.crainbandy.com/programming/using-php-and-simple-html-dom-parser-to-scrape-artist-tour-dates-off-myspace) on just that: scraping myspace for tour dates. Haven't tested it but looks good.